# Angular directive to enable textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following if checkbox is clicked the readonly attribute from the textbox must be removed and on unclicking git should be added.Can this be done by angular directive

```
<div class="radio"> 
     <label>
       <input type="radio">Project</label>
       <input type="text" name="project" id="project" readonly/>
</div>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/xoVYIfWyZQ0xCzZFez8B?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the built-in directive [ngReadonly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="readonly">Project</label>
<input type="text" name="project" id="project" value="" placeholder="Project" ng-readonly="!readonly"/>
```

[**Here's a working plunkr.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTY7kJfgqs9vTkq0QBCv?p=preview)

Comment: but i mentioned inout type="radio" will the code still work

Comment: Sure, check the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTY7kJfgqs9vTkq0QBCv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly:

```
<label>Check me to make text readonly: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
<input type="text" ng-readonly="checked" value="I'm Angular" aria-label="Readonly field" />
```